# data(phiX174Phage) dataset not found in R

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am beginner studying Bioconductor.

I am try to follow lecture of Bioconductor.

```
source("https://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
biocLite("Biostrings")
library(Biostrings)
data(phix174Phage)
```

> Warning message:
>   In data(phix174Phage) not foundError: object 'phix174Phage' not found.

What did I wrong?

Answer (score 1):

R is case-sensitive. Try:

```
data(phiX174Phage)
```

with an upper-case `X`, as specified in [the introductory tutorial](http://bioconductor.org/help/course-materials/2015/LearnBioconductorFeb2015/A01.2_IntroductionToBioconductor.html).

Comment: Oh, Thanks. I was stupid.:(

Comment: Not at all, we all make these kinds of errors sometimes :)